# Regex to End of Word

Tags: regex

I'm so close!

I need to match the word 'hanna' to the end of the word with regex. I know the below will match this, but I only want to match letters a-z

```
hanna[\S]*
```

e.g. ...hannafoo will be matched in the below instance

```
test hannafoo bar
```

...but the below won't be matched

```
test hanna-foo bar
```

Comment: Do you know that `^$` are matched literally and are already covered by `\S`?

Comment: Nope, thanks, I've amended my question.

Comment: i don't know why but i read your question as "Regex to End the World". I guess I'm feeling a little apocalyptic today...

Comment: Where do you want to use this regex? PERL, PHP, JavaScript etc?

Comment: Php, I'm using the Search Regex tool via WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but do you need something like:

```
[hH]anna[a-zA-Z]+
```

?

Comment: Thanks but that's just picking up 'hanna' like this http://db.tt/ibM928iQ , there needs to be a letter after it.

Comment: That didn't pick up any results I'm afraid :-(

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works... http://regexr.com?3094g If this is not what you want, you'll need to provide more examples of what you want to match

Comment: Hi thanks pcalcao, it's almost there, but it needs to match either lower or upper case. See here, where it fails http://db.tt/obw4q2Hj

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hanna[a-z]+`

- `\w` : match any letter

  ```
  $ echo -e 'test hanna-foo bar' | perl -ne '/(hanna[a-z]+)/i && print "$1\n"'

  $ echo -e 'test hannafoo bar' | perl -ne '/(hanna[a-z]+)/i && print "$1\n"'
  hannafoo
  ```

**EDIT**

Fixed the regex according to your comment, added code sample.

Is it what you expect : matching the word beginning with hanna, but being longer ?

**EDIT**

Fixed due to latest comments, last try as I really don't understand your problem...

Comment: Thaks but this didn't work because I need to only pick up things where 'hanna' is followed by a letter. You can see in this screenshot that it's picking up just hanna http://db.tt/4U8rByG2

Comment: @SparrwHawk just replace the ? in your regexp by +

Comment: I don't understand what you want... If you want `test hanna-foo bar` to match `hanna-foo`, just change regex to `hanna[\w-]+`

Comment: Basically I want to replace hanna(whatever comes after this BUT NOT SPACES) with just the word hanna. So I need to search for hanna* (to the end of the word). To give some perspective, I deleted the space between hanna and the next word by accident, and need to undo this via regex searching for my mistakes

Comment: You need to defined what a word is in your context: do you expect hanna-2 to match ?

Comment: Hi Bruce, no, this matches dashes, which I don't want. it needs to be letters only. You can see here that it matches dashes http://db.tt/NdizkuoT